# Cómo migrar de react-native 0.57 a 0.60 o superior?

Tags: react-native

Poseo un proyecto en react-native "0.57.8" y deseo migrar a "0.60" o superior debido a que he tenido varios problemas al querer subir una apk a PlayStore entre estos problemas se encuentran:

- Compilación para android 9 ósea API28
- Versión en 64bits

Dependencias de mi proyecto:

```
"dependencies": {
"image-to-base64": "2.0.1",
"native-base": "2.10.0",
"pusher-js": "^4.3.1",
"react": "16.6.3",
"react-native": "0.57.8",
"react-native-camera": "1.9.1",
"react-native-datepicker": "^1.7.2",
"react-native-elements": "0.19.1",
"react-native-image-picker": "0.28.0",
"react-native-image-resizer": "1.0.0",
"react-native-onesignal": "^3.2.12",
"react-native-qrcode-scanner": "^1.2.1",
"react-native-searchable-dropdown": "^1.0.6",
"react-native-simple-time-picker": "0.2.0",
"react-native-vector-icons": "6.1.0",
"react-navigation": "2.17.0",
"react-navigation-redux-helpers": "2.0.6",
"react-redux": "5.0.7",
"redux": "4.0.1",
"redux-persist": "5.10.0",
"rn-fetch-blob": "^0.10.15",
"toggle-switch-react-native": "2.0.2",
"underscore": "1.9.1"  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

En mi caso lo resolví de la siguiente manera:

- Ejecutar `npm install`

A continuación aparece este mensaje o un mensaje similiar:

`found 1040 vulnerabilities (69 low, 3 moderate, 967 high, 1 critical)
  run 'npm audit fix' to fix them, or 'npm audit' for details`

- Ejecutar `npm audit fix`

Puede aparecer este mensaje o un mensaje similar:

`2 package updates for 67 vulnerabilities involved breaking changes
  (use 'npm audit fix --force' to install breaking changes; or refer to 'npm 
  audit' for steps to fix these manually)`

en ese caso:

- Ejecutar `npm audit fix --force`

Las nuevas dependencias quedarán así o parecidas:

```
"dependencies": {
    "image-to-base64": "2.0.1",
    "native-base": "^2.13.8",
    "pusher-js": "^4.3.1",
    "react": "16.6.3",
    "react-native": "^0.61.4",
    "react-native-camera": "1.9.1",
    "react-native-datepicker": "^1.7.2",
    "react-native-elements": "0.19.1",
    "react-native-image-picker": "0.28.0",
    "react-native-image-resizer": "1.0.0",
    "react-native-onesignal": "^3.5.0",
    "react-native-qrcode-scanner": "^1.2.1",
    "react-native-searchable-dropdown": "^1.0.6",
    "react-native-simple-time-picker": "0.2.0",
    "react-native-splash-screen": "^3.2.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "6.1.0",
    "react-navigation": "2.17.0",
    "react-navigation-redux-helpers": "2.0.6",
    "react-redux": "5.0.7",
    "redux": "4.0.1",
    "redux-persist": "5.10.0",
    "rn-fetch-blob": "^0.10.15",
    "toggle-switch-react-native": "2.0.2",
    "underscore": "1.9.1"
  }
```

- Eliminar carpetas android y ios
- Volver a generar carpetas android y ios [react-native-eject npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-eject):

  `npm i react-native-eject 
  yarn add react-native-eject 
  react-native eject`

Con esto se solventan los errores de compilar en SDK Objetivo 28 y 64 bits